# WPF - Background Worker does not want to stop

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I'm trying to update a WPF `TreeView` where each root node contiains several sub-nodes, so I load sub-nodes "on demand" using the `TreeView_Expanded` event.

When a node is Expanded the `FillFolder` method in the ViewModel is called. This method calls the `RunWorkerAsync` on the main `BackgroundWorker` in this way:

```
public void FillFolder(SCADAFolder selectedFolder)
{
    _bwWorker.CancelAsync();
    _bwWorker.RunWorkerAsync(selectedFolder);
}
```

I call the `CancelAsync` method because what happens is that if I expand a node with thousands of sub-nodes and before it ends I open another sub-node, this one will be filled with the sub-nodes of the first node opened, because the loop is still adding items.

This is how my BackroundWorker is declared:

```
private BackgroundWorker _bwWorker;

//Constructor
{
    _bwWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _bwWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    _bwWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    _bwWorker.DoWork += _bwWorker_DoWork;
    _bwWorker.ProgressChanged += _bwWorker_ProgressChanged;
    _bwWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += _bwWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    [...]
}
```

And this is what the `BackgroundWorker` actually does:

```
void _bwWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    [do a query...]

    foreach (DataRowView rowView in QueryResults)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            selectedFolder.Items.Clear();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            MyItem item = CreateItem();//pseudo code here

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => selectedFolder.Items.Add(item)));
        }
    }
}
```

but the `CancellationPending` condition is never true.

Why?

**EDIT**

Solved using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...)` instead of `BackgroundWorker` and using `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke`

Comment: Aren't you getting an exception when you call RunWorkerAsync right after CancelAsync? You should wait for the cancellation to complete before you restart the worker.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: I bet he would if it were still running, but I think his worker has already exited and he only thinks it is still running because all the queued adds are still being processed. Guess we'll find out.

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing that cancellation isn't working? Is your only test that items continue to be added? You are adding your items via `BeginInvoke`. Since this is asynchronous, your worker may have already finished but items continue to be added.

You have a race condition because `CancelAsync` doesn't wait for the worker to stop. You should be passing `selectedFolder` into the worker as a parameter and using that parameter when performing the append, not using whatever folder happens to be selected at the time.

Note that `selectedFolder.Items.Clear();` needs to be called from within a `BeginInvoke` also.